# Bug in Google Play apps testing

Tags: android, testing, google-play, beta, beta-testing

I have several problems with google play apps testing.

I have a beta user group with 100 users.

In the process given from google, I must add all users to a group, and then, when user receive a mail, he click a blue button "Become a tester"

I have 2 problems in this step.

1. I don't have a way to know who clicked this button and who didn't click, so I really don't have control of who has the correct version
2. After clicking blue button, when user has 2 google accounts, it fails, even if the user choose the correct email. I was able to pass this step by deleting an account, download app, and re-add the account. It seems like a bug to me.

So basically, I have a lot of trouble with all this process.

Is there any way to get it work better, or should I just buy an external service?

Answer (score 0):

```
1. I don't have a way to know who clicked this button and who didn't click, so I really don't have control of who has the correct version
```

Well it is true that you don't get a "notification" per say saying that the user clicked the blue button. But you can always look up the developer console to see who has downloaded the app based on versions, devices etc etc.

```
2. After clicking blue button, when user has 2 google accounts, it fails, even if the user choose the correct email. I was able to pass this step by deleting an account, download app, and re-add the account. It seems like a bug to me. So basically, I have a lot of trouble with all this process.
```

I never experienced that when i was added to a beta testing group. I actually had 3 accounts on my phone at that time and was still able to install the beta app without any issues.

**EDIT:**

Link to the play store stats & reports doc:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?hl=en

Comment: Can you detail the point 1 please, I don't know how to see who has which version. For the point 2, even if you don't experimented this problem, if user is logged with another google account that the one that you have registered ( enterprise account vs personal account ), user will get an error message, and user will not get beta version :(

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?hl=en.. check the link..take a look at the dimensions & filter block

Comment: ohh, I see, I need to integrate Google Analytics... I already use Crashlytics for crash reports, it may be a little heavy to include Google Analytics, but will think about it !